# Red, yellow and green lights on iTunes

Tags: windows-7, mac, itunes, gui

I notice on some of my friends laptop, the itunes player has three lights where the file edit, veiw, controls and all the other stuff suppose to be. Is that just for Mac system or is it for all laptops?

Comment: maybe add the mac tag?

Comment: @debug Oooh, I have a shiny new "retag" superpower.  Done.

Comment: You are truly a super user.

Answer (score 4):

If you talking about those colorful circle buttons on top-left of the image below, then those are your close, minimize, and maximize buttons. (left-to-right)

[image]

Comment: They appear on most Mac applications and are *roughly* equivalent to the three buttons that appear at the top right of most Windows apps.

Comment: To clarify, those three buttons appear on ONLY Mac systems, not Windows' versions of Mac programs, eg iTunes for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Someone should mention that on the Mac, the menu bar is always at the top of the *screen*, not the top of each *window*. So you just needed to look a little higher to find the menus you needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a post that explains those](http://blogs.ucls.uchicago.edu/is/?p=56). To quote:

> In the upper left hand corner of every
>   window on your Apple computer, you’ll
>   see three buttons: red, yellow, and
>   green.
>
> The red button closes the window but
>   not the application. To close the
>   application, depress the Command key
>   next to your space bar (⌘) with your
>   left thumb and tap the letter Q with
>   your ring finger.
>
> The yellow button minimizes the
>   window. If you click this button,
>   you’ll see the window swoop into your
>   dock. If you want to see the window
>   again, simply click the small icon
>   representing that window and it will
>   swoop back to center stage.
>
> The green button toggles your window
>   between two optimal sizes. One setting
>   usually fills your display height
>   and/or width. You choose the other
>   setting by dragging the bottom right
>   corner of your window up, down, left,
>   or right, until it’s just right. The
>   next time you open that application,
>   your windows will “remember” your
>   settings.